# Accessing auth session data (Lithium + MongoDB)

Tags: lithium

Okay, so hopefully I am asking this question correctly:

I set up my user model & controller, as well as my session model and controller... but I want to render some of the session info onto a page.

*for example*
**If I were to login to a page, it would read "Brian" (or whatever my username is that I used for my login)**

I hope I am not asking a repeated question -- I have searched this question pretty extensively and haven't found a solution yet. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your session (set in a config/bootstrap file) is called "default" then just run **check** ...

```
$user = Auth::check('default');
```

Then **$user** will have an array of the user data in the session, so if you have a **first_name** field in your database/session you could do:

```
echo $user["first_name"];
```

I created a helper to clean this up a little, I called it: **extensions/helper/Login.php**

```
<?php

namespace app\extensions\helper;
use lithium\security\Auth;

class Login extends \lithium\template\Helper {

    public function user() {

        $user = Auth::check('default');

        return $user;
    }

    public function fullName() {

        $user = self::user();

        return $user["first_name"] . " " . $user["last_name"];
    }

}

?>
```

Then in my Views I used it like ...

```
<?=$this->login->fullName(); ?>
```

Comment: What would this look like in the controller?

Comment: It would work just like the example above but you'd do the Auth:check() and $user["first_name"] inside the controller instead.